# How do I stop GIMP flattening layers when exporting TIFF file

Tags: export, gimp, tiff, layers

I have some psd files with layers that I would like to process in paint dot net. However, that program won't read .psd files.

I do have GIMP, which I really hate using because of its idiosyncratic interface.  It reads the .psd file fine though.

GIMP allegedly will export to TIFF (which supports layers), however GIMP flattens all the layers without asking or warning.

So my question is, how do I get the .psd file (with layers intact) into paint dot net?

-----Edited for clarity-------

I had two questions:
1. How to stop GIMP flattening layers when exporting to TIFF
2. What is the best way to get a .psd file into paint dot net

(Obviously, I do not have photoshop, and to get it would be a lot of $$$ for a one off file conversion.  The files were not created by me).

Thanks for the suggestions re #2.   I'm still curious about #1

Additional comments:

I'm curious as to why paint dot net would not support importing of .psd files.  That would seem to be a significant limitation.  Also, it does seem a lot harder to transfer files with multiple layers between programs than single layer files - just wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154715) based on the version of Photoshop used to create the PSD file.

Have you tried [saving the PSD as an older version of Photoshop](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130930160031AAJnSx6)?

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions:

Option 1 (best bet of it working as you expect):

- Get Photoshop.
- Use it to save the PSD as a TIFF or another format you desire.

Option 2:

- Use one of the several online image converters.
- I've personally had good luck with [www.zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/psd-to-tiff/) in the past, but I can't attest to it's ability to keep TIFF layers though.
- Other sites that offer similar: http://psdviewer.org/ConvertPsdToTiff.aspx, http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-tiff